# Rotate texture sfml and save output to file

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

I want to start out by saying I am a complete c++ novice. I do not know any of the vocabulary associated with it so if this question is trivial I apologies, as I do not now the correct terms or phrases to google the solution myself.

Currently playing around with this code I found on github to capture gameplay from my 3ds.
https://github.com/Gotos/Cute3DSCapture/blob/master/main.cpp

I am trying to add the ability to rotate the image and save it to a png file.

from `main.cpp` around lines 267 I am trying to add the following functionality.

```
sprite.setTexture(texture);
sprite.rotate(90);
texture = sprite.getTexture();
texture.copyToImage().saveToFile("Something/Place/img.png");
```

Current texture and sprite are defined as the following.

```
sf::Texture texture;
sf::Sprite sprite;
```

When I try to build and run I get the followin

```
main.cpp:269:25: error: no viable overloaded '='
                texture = sprite.getTexture();
                ~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/SFML/Graphics/Texture.hpp:421:14: note: candidate function
      not viable: no known conversion from 'const sf::Texture *' to
      'const sf::Texture' for 1st argument; dereference the argument with *
    Texture& operator =(const Texture& right);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try `sprite.getTexture()->copyToImage().saveToFile("Something/Place/img.png");` directly

Comment: @MiMo this will simply produce a copy of the original image, not a modified version. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sf::Sprite` is not a texture manipulator, which means that the texture returned by `sf::Sprite::getTexture()` will not be modified. That's why the Sprite's ctor takes a reference to a `const` texture instance.

If you're solely interested in image manipulation, I'd recommend using something else than SFML as you might get better features/performance for specific operations. Probably something like imagemagick.

With SFML, you can do it roughly like this:

- Create a [`RenderTexture`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.3.2/classsf_1_1RenderTexture.php) of the desired size -- think of this as a virtual window that give you access to its texture when `.display()` has been called.
- Create your sprite using your initial texture and some manipulation (e.g. rotation) -- make sure that the size of the render texture is correctly set to "display" the resulting image
- Draw your sprite on the render texture and call `display()` on it.
- Then you can call `sf::RenderTexture::getTexture()` and chain `copyToImage()` and `saveToFile()`.

Look at the detailed description of `sf::RenderTexture` for an example of use.

Comment: Thanks, I deleted my answer. I must admit I have barely used SFML and I didn't read the `sf::Sprite` documentation. It seems to me the OP has more fundamental things to learn before tackling image manipulation!

Comment: Thanks, I have no experience with pointers or references in general. I originally used SFML because that was the source code I found online that was compatible with my 3ds capture software and able to quickly output an iamge. 
I am more familiar with OpenCV and was able to manipulate the image there.
http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Core.html

Answer (score 0):

You could just add another `sf::Texture Newtexture = sprite.getTexture(); Newtexture.copyToImage().saveToFile("Something/Place/img.png");`